# connect to rabbitMQ cloud using django docker

Tags: django, docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to follow a "Microservices Application with Django, Flask, Mysql" guide on youtube.
In this example a Django app uses RabbitMQ (cloud version) to send the message that must be consumed. The following is the consumer.py

```
import pika
params = pika.URLParameters('amqps_key')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='admin')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print('Recevied in admin')
    print(body)


channel.basic_consume(queue='admin', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

print('Started cosuming')

channel.start_consuming()

channel.close()
```

I have an endpoint in the urls.py that calls the producer.py

This is the docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh","db:3306","--","python","manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:8000"]

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.36
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: tutorial_ms_admin
      MYSQL_USER: ms_admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ms_admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ms_admin
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
```

Now: if I start the docker-compose, then open a terminal, go inside the backend service and in the service shell type "python consumer.py", using Postman and enter the endpoint I can see the message being consumed (both in  screen and in the rabbit cloud administration panel).

If I tried to add the python consumer.py as a command after the "wait-for-it.sh.... " it does not work. Messages are stuck in the Rabbit cloud administration panel, as if nothing consumes them.
Basically i would like not to open a terminal to start the consumer.py but to make it start automatically as soon as the backend service runserver has started

I cannot understand how to fix this.

EDIT:

Following the youtube lesson I should have create the service for handling the call to RabbitMQ cloud, but that is the point where I stucked. I simplified the problem otherwise it would have been too difficult to explain clearly for me.
The amqps_key is the key I get from RabbitMQ Cloud to access a free channel to exchange message, so

```
params = pika.URLParameters('amqps_key')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
```

is where the scripts knows where to access the channel.

The script consumer.py is inside the backend (Django) service structure. So after I launch the docker-compose I open a terminal, enter inside the running service (docker-compose exec backend sh) and run

```
python consumer.py
```

Then using postman when I hit 127.0.0.1:8000/api/products I can see the message received in the terminal (so the message started from that endpoint, reached the RabbitMQ cloud channel and the consumer.py is able to listen to that channel and consume the message).

If I try to set the python consumer.py at the docker-compose startup it doesn't work. Neither if i try to setup a service that tries to handle that.

For the first solution I tried different approaches, as variation of:

```
command: bash -c "python consumer.py && ./wait-for-it.sh db:3306 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:800"
```

For the second approach, following that guide, I setup a service as such:

```
    version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh","db:3306","--","python","manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:8000"]


  queue:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - backend
    command: 'python consumer.py'
  
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.36
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: tutorial_ms_admin
      MYSQL_USER: ms_admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ms_admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ms_admin
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
```

Comment: I don't see a RabbitMQ container in your `docker-compose.yml` file; are you missing this?  Similarly, how are you launching this script as a container?  What configuration are you using to tell the script where to connect to the RabbitMQ broker (what does `amqps_key` refer to)?

Comment: I edited the question trying to be more specific